# Face Detection with Emgu CV in C# and WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I am doing Face Detection with `Emgu CV` in C# and `WPF`,the problem is my program is getting run,but nothing is displayed in the window-

CODE IS-

```
MainWindow.xaml

<Window x:Class="FaceRecognition.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="600" Width="800" Loaded="Window_Loaded">
    <Grid>
        <Image Name="image1" Stretch="Fill"></Image>
    </Grid>
</Window>

MainWindow.xaml.cs

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using Emgu.CV.Structure;
using Emgu.CV;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows.Threading;
using System.Drawing;

namespace FaceRecognition
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        private Capture capture;
        private HaarCascade haarCascade;
        DispatcherTimer timer;
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            capture = new Capture();
            haarCascade = new HaarCascade(@"haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml");
            timer = new DispatcherTimer();
            timer.Tick += new EventHandler(timer_Tick);
            timer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
            timer.Start();
        }


        void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Image<Bgr, Byte> currentFrame = capture.QueryFrame();

            if (currentFrame != null)
            {
                Image<Gray, Byte> grayFrame = currentFrame.Convert<Gray, Byte>();

                var detectedFaces = grayFrame.DetectHaarCascade(haarCascade)[0];

                foreach (var face in detectedFaces)
                    currentFrame.Draw(face.rect, new Bgr(0, double.MaxValue, 0), 3);

                image1.Source = ToBitmapSource(currentFrame);
            }

        }


        [DllImport("gdi32")]
        private static extern int DeleteObject(IntPtr o);

        public static BitmapSource ToBitmapSource(IImage image)
        {
            using (System.Drawing.Bitmap source = image.Bitmap)
            {
                IntPtr ptr = source.GetHbitmap(); //obtain the Hbitmap

                BitmapSource bs = System.Windows.Interop.Imaging.CreateBitmapSourceFromHBitmap(
                    ptr,
                    IntPtr.Zero,
                    Int32Rect.Empty,
                    System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapSizeOptions.FromEmptyOptions());

                DeleteObject(ptr); //release the HBitmap
                return bs;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have also added all the references required of `Emgu dll` files,and also added all the `openCV` dll files in the following folder-

```
D:\dot net\handouts\handoutsprogram\FaceRecognition\FaceRecognition\bin\Debug
```

Comment: No faces have been detected?

Comment: yes,no faces are detected and also when I close the application this exception is coming-The type initializer for 'Emgu.CV.CvInvoke' threw an exception.